# Python Discord Bot Error With Concatenation

Tags: python, windows, discord

I have a problem when trying to send the Cool Meter message, what is the issue?
Also on line 12 the syntax says that you can't add a + b (a + b being an example) so when I run it , the script automatically says an error.  In fact I tried just putting the contents on line 12 inside on the message function but the error still happened.

```
import discord
import os
import random
import time
import requests
import json

client = discord.Client()

Numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100]

RandomNumber = random.choice(Numbers) + str"% Cool."

def get_quote():
  response = requests.get("https://zenquotes.io/api/random")
  json_data = json.loads(response.text)
  quote = json_data[0]["q"] + " -"+json_data[0]["a"]
  return(quote)

#On Ready Event.
@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("Bot Ready.")
  time.sleep(1)
  print("Logged In As:  {0.user}".format(client))

#If The Bot Recieves A Message Event.
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return

  if message.content.startswith(":quote"):
    quote = get_quote()
    await message.channel.send(quote)
  elif message.content.startswith(":coolmeter"):
    await message.channel.send(RandomNumber)

client.run(os.getenv("Token"))
```

Comment: Well, you can't add strings to numbers.

Comment: Oh, I'm kind of new.  Is there a way to do something similar though?

Comment: `RandomNumber = f"{random.choice(Numbers)} Cool."`